# Can't send email through SendGrid

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid

I'm following the example from [SendGrid's site](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/csharp.html) and as credentials I'm pasting it what they gave me in the Azure portal. Still, I get this error message.

> Message = {"Failure sending mail."}
>   InnerException = {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

I'm not clear on what to do here, not even how to debug it. I'm running the code from the desktop (before I put it on the site) so I can break-point myself through it. However, to no joy...

Suggestions?

Full code below.

```
MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name"));
mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("from@example.com", "From Name");
mailMsg.Subject = "subject";
string text = "text body";
string html = @"<p>html body</p>";
mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
  text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
  html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
  "azure_...@azure.com",
  "LubX........pQc");
client.Credentials = credentials;
client.Send(mailMsg);
```

Comment: Did you try sending to a valid email address? Perhaps the mail service is trying to connect to "example.com" - there is obviously no such address.

Comment: yes, see if you have any log entries at https://sendgrid.com/logs/index

Comment: @chuex I have a valid address, yes.

Comment: @bwest It appears tha tthe maila are sent out when I execute the application on my Azure account. However, the same server seems to bark at me when I attempt to utilize it from console application. Is that intended behavior?!

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference as far as I know!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Were you able to get this working? I tried this same logic in a Web application as suggested in the answers below. However, I could not get it working locally when I try to debug the code in localhost. I am using VS Express 2013 for Web with update 5. Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: @KRM It was over five years ago so my memory might be a bit fuzzy on this point. I recall that it turned out that you only could run the mail deliveries from the cloud uploaded version. Later on, they did introduce the option of mailing from anywhere, though, but it might have been removed (or I recall wrong).

Comment: Thanks @KonradViltersten, I appreciate your quick response to this!

Comment: @KRM I just verified how it's resolved in my latest solution. I skipped SendGrid all toghether because there was something unclear about the amount of free mass. I applied another service, equivalent in setup. In the project before that I used my own SMTP I'm using for my private email (so it's payable but not extra for me which works as the number of mail sent that way in that particular case is rather limited). Feel free to give some feed-back here on which you chose and your experience of it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I really appreciate checking back on your solution and confirming me. So, I could get the SendGrid working after deploying. But it still doesn't work locally. But I am fine with it as of now since it works after deployment. But I wanted to know more about your comment on amount of free mass . I see it says 2500 free mails/month in Azure free pricing tier for SendGrid. Do you think that's not true or it has some hidden cost etc. which is why you choose some other service?

Comment: @KRM No hidden costs as far I recall. 2500 boinks per month (if they say so, it's probably correct) seems like a sufficient amount but if you target 500 people and send a welcome mail, test mail and one more, then you suddenly have passed half of your quota and we had the procedure - mail when you register interest, confirmation mail, password reset request, initial info, confirmation. And during development, well... I make a lot of mistakes so we needed to resend and resend.   :)   But no trickeries or gotchas - it's a fair play company.

Comment: Thank you @KonradViltersten!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this happen to be a console application? I've been testing SendGrid and found that when I try to send an email from a Console application the emails are never sent. However, when I tried it from a web application (using the same exact sending code) the emails are sent. I have no explanation for why the console application does not work.

Comment: Well, I do, I think. When the application is run from the console, it doesn't count as cloud-driven, hence not being included in the security schema. There's some firewall or something like that simply blocking it. One needs to execute it from the cloud or pay the higher amount to get the mail delivered from the console. I'm guessing it's some kind of fraud protection. +1 for the effort of checking old questions.

Comment: It does work in a console app but you need to call it like this for some reason: transportWeb.DeliverAsync(msg).Wait().  More here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/154

Comment: If, like me, you are now wondering what in the world "transportWeb" is, it appears to be referencing this example: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/csharp.html#  However, I couldn't get that example to work; after installing the SendGrid C# NuGet package ("Install-Package SendGrid"), it appeared to include no definition of the object SendGrid.SendGridMessage as used in the example.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a SendGrid email send to happen successfully from a Console application using the [SendGrid v3 C# API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/csharp.html).

I first needed to import the SendGrid C# library via NuGet using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

```
PM> Install-Package SendGrid
```

Then, my code:

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ...

public static async Task SendEmailViaSendGrid(string to, string from, string subject, string body)
{
    // Generated from https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys
    // TODO: Store this somewhere secure -- not in version control.
    string apiKey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_SENDGRID_API_KEY_GOES_HERE";

    dynamic sendGridClient = new SendGridAPIClient(apiKey);

    Email fromEmail = new Email(from);
    Email toEmail = new Email(to);
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", body);
    Mail mail = new Mail(fromEmail, subject, toEmail, content);

    dynamic response = await sendGridClient.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool SendMailBySendGrid(string offMail, string mailFormatDetails,string subject,string ccMail=null,string bccMail=null)
{
  string mailFromId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sender"];
  SendGridMessage sndmsg = new SendGridMessage();
  sndmsg.From = new MailAddress(mailFromId);
  sndmsg.To = new MailAddress[] { new MailAddress(offMail) };
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccMail))
    sndmsg.Cc = new MailAddress[] { new MailAddress(ccMail) };
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bccMail))
    sndmsg.Bcc = new MailAddress[] { new MailAddress(bccMail) };
  sndmsg.Subject = subject;         
  sndmsg.Html = "<div>" + mailFormatDetails + "</div>";
  bool result= SendEmail(sndmsg);
  return result;
}
```

Include *using SendGrid;* in your project.

Comment: Can you confirm if you execute the code above from a console application or from a website (and if the latter, could you, please, specify how it's hosted)? The reason for me asking is that I got that to work right away when executed from an Azure website but not other wise. However, things might have change over time.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I found out why emails are not sent from a console application. When I add Console.Read(); at the end of the program.cs class, it sends the emails, but if I remove the Console.Read(); from the code, the emails do not send. So my assumption is, if I let the program wait a bit before it closes, the emails should send.

Comment: If **this** is the case, I'd judge it so wrong... So wrong... My program executes, established the connection to the cloud API, pushes out some mails and then can die. Let the software in the cloud do its job, for God's sake! Why does it need to keep a connection to my console program? Anyway, +1 for an interesting suggestion. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It worked for me, if it helps, you can try using Thread.Sleep(60000) at the end of your code which is what I used and it worked. Without that, my emails would not send at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case for everyone, but I had to create a Sender. https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth/senders. That would match `mailMsg.From`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, **I think I have the answer**. Above code is fine. On SendGrid you must approve the sending email address. Log into your SendGrid portal and attend to the below:

1. Setting -> Sender Authentication
2. Under "Single Sender Verification" add the email address that you want
3. Click authorize link in inbox and your bob's nephew.

Hope the above helps

Comment: The question is 6 years old and got an accepted answer long time ago. The problem was that it didn't work from a local desktop application. One had to upload the app to the cloud and run it from there. (That's the state back then. I don't know how it works today.)

Comment: yeah, i had the error for a long time and only the above worked. So maybe someone else that has the same problem may just be missing the above step.